# File upload through table in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2, multiple-file-upload

I have to upload multiple files at a time. I have added these files in a table. I want to send these files added in the table to my action class. but I am not able to do so??

my jquery is like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#table").hide();
        $("#table1").hide();                        
        $('#fileButton').on("click",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

by this files are being added  in the table

```
function addFile() {
    var fileName = $("#myFile").val();

    if(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')!=-1) {
        fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    } else if(fileName.lastIndexOf('\\')!=-1){
        fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('\\')+1);
    }

    if(!isFilePresent(fileName)){
        $("#table").show();
        $("#table1").show();
        var row = '<tr><td class="filename">'+fileName+'</td></tr>';
        $("#myTable tbody").append(row);
    }   
    $("#myFile").val("");
}
```

This is my form

```xml
<form action="documentUpload" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:file label="File (1)" id="myFile" name="upload" /> 

    <input type="button" value="ADD" class="Button" 
             id="fileButton" onclick="addFile();"/>

    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <div>File Type</div>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <s:submit  value="Upload" id="table1"/>
</form>
```

This is my struts.xml entry

```xml
<action name="documentUpload" class="objDocumentUpload" method="upload">
    <result name="success">/jsp/documentUpload2.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/jsp/dashboard.jsp</result>
</action>
```

This is my action class.

```
public class FileUploadAction {
    private List<File> uploads = new ArrayList<File>();

    public String upload() throws Exception {    
        int upload12=uploads.size();
        System.out.println(upload12);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

I am successfully able to add files in the table. when I am clicking on upload button, the control is transferred to my action class. But in the upload method I am getting the size in `upload12` as zero.

Please provide me any helpful solution so that I can upload file through table

Comment: That's too bad. But without any actual information I'm not sure how you expect anybody to be able to help.

Comment: @xrcwrn i have added by code. please have a look

Comment: @DaveNewton i have added my code. please have a look

Comment: This may be helpfull for you http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-UploadingMultipleFilesusingArrays

Comment: @xrcwrn but i want to know how can we send the value of file added in table to my action class

Comment: Your first point of failure is where you expect the data you added to an HTML table in JS to get posted to the server, much less the content of the files.  First start by dynamically creating file input objects.  What you're trying to do is bit more complicated than your attempted implementation.  You'll probably have to roll up your sleeves and do away with the struts tags.  Even if the data was getting posted from the browser properly, I don't see anything in place that would drop it in the "uploads" list in your action.  Have you successfully processed a regular single file upload?

Answer (score 0):

Your table is just a client display and won't be used during the POST.
Instead of table rows, you need to create "file" fields in your form.

Comment: Better to give this suggestion as comment